# The unequal width between axes causes non-diagonal lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
x=np.arange(-2,4,0.1)
y1=x
y2=-x
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
```

Now I have drawn a graph of y=x and y=-x.
[image]

It's known to all that y=x and y=-x should be diagonal lines. However, because of the inequality of width between x axis and y axis with the same 1 unit distance, the lines are not diagonal.

That's a wrong graph.

I have also set the canvas to be a square to avoid such problem. It doesn't work.

How to draw a correct y=x and y=-x?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: y = x and y = -x are not vertical. They are diagonal. In fact, they look exactly like your plots :-)

Comment: I guess what you want to say is that y = x and y = -x are perpendicular to each other

Comment: y=x and y=-x are perpendicular. It's undoubtedly.

Comment: Then what do you mean by vertical? How can `y=x` and `y=-x` be vertical? You can achieve what I think you want by using equal size in both directions. Using `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))` worked perfectly fine for me. You can choose any other number as well

Comment: I edited the question. "vertical" is simply the wrong word here.

Comment: add `plt.xlim((-2,4)); plt.ylim((-2,4))` to your code

Comment: @Bazingaa `figsize=(8,8)` does not work, because of the default unequal margins of the subplot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Oh yes you are right. I used -4 to 4 as the x range so didn't notice. Thanks for pointing it out. Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for an equal aspect ratio:

```
plt.axis("equal")
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I want! thanks a lot! It seems that I did't use the word 'vertical' correctly！